# Pipe sed capture group through external program before replacing?

Tags: regex, sed, replace, pipe, capture-group

Is there a way for `sed` to pipe a capture group to another program,  making `\1` in the regexp's RHS equal to the output of that program?

For example, running

```
sed 's/lorem ipsum \(foobar\)/\1/g' file.txt
```

would pipe "foobar" through another program (e.g., `tr 'o' 'a'`) to make `\1` be "faabar" for `sed` to replace "lorem ipsum foobar" with "lorem ipsum faabar"?

<sup>This is just a simple example. I realize I could convert "foobar" to "faabar" without using `tr`.</sup>

Comment: Post input and expected output sample.  It may be solved other way that you think.

Comment: @Jotne I've added a fuller working example.

Comment: GNU `sed` has an `/x` option; but what you are trying is wrong on so many levels. Use a tool with a proper HTML parser. Your code could rather easily be reimplemented in Perl but then doesn't PHP have a facility for that too (let alone one for reading a file line by line and applying a regex. Not that I'd recommend PHP for anything)?

Comment: There's a famous joke about trying to parse HTML with regex, but [we are not supposed to link to it.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261561/please-stop-linking-to-the-zalgo-anti-cthulhu-regex-rant)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the execute option:

> `e`
>   This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space. If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output. A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command to be executed contains a NUL character. This is a GNU sed extension.

([source](https://superuser.com/a/1496401/261550); [original source](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command))